# Adding a new entity to a bound DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

I have `Companies` and `Contracts` in a parent-child relationship, shown in two DataGridViews in a winforms app. They are both bound to collections of Entity models.

How can I add a new contract?

1. If I do this,

   ```
   Dim c as Company = CompaniesBindingSource.Current
   c.contracts.Add(New Contract())
   context.SaveChanges()
   ```

   the grid doesn't refresh (even if I call `.Refresh()`, or `.ResetBindings()` on the BindingSource. I have to navigate away from the selected company and back to it, for the grid to refresh.
2. If I do `ContractsBindingSource.AddNew()`, the grid refreshes, but the data doesn't persist to my entity context.

Note: my contracts collection is a property on my `Company` model:

```
Public ReadOnly Property activeContracts As SortableBindingList(Of Contract)
    Get
        Dim list = New SortableBindingList(Of Contract)

        For Each contract As Contract In contracts.Where(Function(c) c.isActive).ToList
            list.Add(contract)
        Next

        Return list
    End Get
End Property
```

Does this have anything to do with it? How can I force a property to recompute?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
CompaniesBindingSource.ResetCurrentItem()
```

This recalculated the `Contracts` property, and automatically refreshed the contracts grid.